# Versioning for Rails i18n translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, versioning, rails-i18n

I'm in the process of building a volunteer based translation engine for a new site built in Rails 4.0. Since it's volunteer based, there is always the possibility that a user may enter a translation that others do not agree with, accidentally remove a translation, etc. In such an event, I would like to give users the option to revert to a previous translation.

I did some searching around but have yet to find a solution aside from writing my own I18n backend. Is there a simpler way of storing previous versions of translations?

I'm currently using [Sven Fuchs' Active Record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record) as a backend, however I'm seriously thinking about switching due to possible performance issues later on down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a very successful experience using **Globalize** (github page: https://github.com/globalize/globalize) and as for the versioning part we didn't try it but Globalize does have support for that in a seperate gem github page: (https://github.com/globalize/globalize-versioning)

After tens of painful gem experiences, i found that comparing gems by last update date and how frequent is new releases, bugs fixes and support is a major factor to decide which one will make your life easier and which one won't.

**Update:**

You can use Globalize to dynamically translate views ([check tutorial](http://www.gaugeus.com/ramblings/2007/11/15/view-translation-globalizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application-by-adding-multilingual-support-to-the-views)) but i came across a github project called **iye**. I think it suits your needs best (github page: https://github.com/firmafon/iye)

Comment: Thanks but it looks to me like Globalize only stores translated text for models, not for otherwise static site content (the stuff that comes stored by default in YAML files).

Comment: @Godwin so you are trying to translate views? not site content, right !!

Comment: sorry still leaning the basics for Rails. Yes views.

Comment: @Godwin i am not a pro in Rails neither :) , check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much @Nimir, I really appreciate your help. I was able to find a solution after looking at how Globalize Versioning works.

Answer (score 0):

I used Nimir's help to find this solution. Like Globalize Versioning, you can add [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) support for the [Active Record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record)'s `Translation` class, however there are a few pitfalls to this method currently.

First you need to include the gems in your Gemfile:

```
gem "i18n-active_record"
gem "paper_trail"
```

Then you need to make sure your `Translation` model class is inheriting from I18n Active Record::Translation and call and calls `has_paper_trail`:

```
class Translation < I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation
    has_paper_trail
end
```

This should really be enough, however the `store_translations` method in `I18n Active Record` do not update existing records. Instead, each time a record is added, all records with the given key are deleted and a new record is created. This causes confusion for Paper Trail since it relied on an id.

To get around this issue, I created my own `store_translation` method, which will update records if they exist:

```
def store_translations(locale, data, options = {})
    escape = options.fetch(:escape, true)
    I18n.backend.flatten_translations(locale, data, escape, false).each do |key, value|
        t = Translation.find_or_create_by!(locale: locale.to_s, key: key.to_s)
        t.value = value
        t.save
    end
    I18n.backend.reload!
end
```

Notice I also included `I18n.backend.reload!`, this is because I am running `Memoize` to cache translations but it seems that it needs to be told to recache whenever a record is updated.

Now I can simply call:

```
store_translations(lang, {key => key}, :escape => false)
```

to a store a new translation and ensure we keep a record of the old one and who made the change.